# Angular 4 - param of Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I'm creating a button which on click it loads all items from array i default way it should splice it to (0,3). I have problem with this implementation. Is there any way to set default param e.g. = 'a' and if 'b' load all? This button should be used like **show more** buttons.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "reverse"
})
export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, param: any) {

    if (param) {
        value.reverse();
      if (param === "a") {
        return value.reverse().slice(0, 3);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items > 0" > 
    <div *ngFor="let review of product$ | async | reverse:param; let i = index" >
      <ngb-rating [(rate)]="review.rate" [readonly]="true"></ngb-rating> {{review.rate}}

      <p>{{i+1}}.) {{ review.description.description }}</p>
      <br />
      <ng-container *ngIf="review.user">
      <p class="float-right">Dodał użytkownik: {{ review.user }}</p>
    </ng-container>
      <hr>

    </div>
    <button *ngIf="items > 3" (click)="param = 'a'">Pokaż wszystkie</button>
  </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can set default paramaters in Typescript

```
 transform(value: any, param: any='a') {
    //...
 }
```

Comment: The problem is, when i set to 'a' i'm getting my new array without 3 slices records, i need them to show all, i need some copy before slice

Comment: I wrote splice :P not slice, when i was writing to you i figured out hehe ;D